# how can i upgrade my caffe model so it doesn't 'upgrade' every time I use it

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using caffe with python(pycaffe).  I am using the prebuilt [alexnet model from model zoo](http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel).

from this page:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_alexnet

Every time I use the model, with this code:

```
net = caffe.Classifier('deploy.prototxt','bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel',
                   channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                   raw_scale=255,
                   image_dims=(256, 256))
```

caffe tells me the file format is old and it needs to upgrade the file.  Shouldn't this happen only once?

> ```
> E0304 20:52:57.356480 12716 upgrade_proto.cpp:609] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated transformation parameters: /tmp/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel
> I0304 20:52:57.356554 12716 upgrade_proto.cpp:612] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated data transformation parameters.     E0304 20:52:57.356564 12716 upgrade_proto.cpp:614] Note that future Caffe releases will only support transform_param messages for transformation fields.
> E0304 20:52:57.356580 12716 upgrade_proto.cpp:618] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter: /tmp/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel
> I0304 20:52:59.307096 12716 upgrade_proto.cpp:626] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated V1LayerParameter
> ```

how can I properly upgrade the file so that this doesn't happen every single time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you load the model caffe upgrades your prototxt and binary proto, but does not override the original files you are using. This is why you keep getting this message.

Upgrading is very straight forward. In `$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools` you'll find two binaries: `upgrade_net_proto_binary` and `upgrade_net_proto_text`. Simply apply them to your `deploy.prototxt` and `bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel` and save the results:

```
~$ mv deploy.prototxt deploy_old.prototxt
~$ mv bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel bvlc_alexnet_old.caffemodel
~$ $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text deploy_old.prototx deploy.prototxt
~$ $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary bvlc_alexnet_old.caffemodel bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for Shai for your [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35967309/1714410).
However, if you are in **Windows** `upgrade_net_proto_binary` and `upgrade_net_proto_text` .exe files are in `path-to-caffe-master/caffe/build/tools/Release`.

Hope this will help Windows users